# how to create methods in Javascript and OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to create an object in JavaScript and I'm following [Mozilla's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) . the tutorial works just fine, but when I apply that technique to my code it doesn't work. (I'm doing something wrong but I don't see it). I coded all my methods and I don't get any errors, I initialize my object and I don't get any errors either, I even call my methods and I don't get errors, but the return value is a string with my code instead of the value that I'm expecting

```
function JavaScriptObj(id, datatype) {
    function initialize(id, datatype) {
        if (typeof id === 'number' && id > 1) {
            this.theID = id;
        } else {
            console.error("ERROR: JavaScriptObj.initialize" + id + "is NOT a valid argument");
        }

        if (typeof datatype === 'string') {
            this.data_type = datatype;
        } else {
            console.error("ERROR: JavaScriptObj.initialize" + datatype + "is NOT a valid argument");
        }
    }
}

JavaScriptObj.prototype.getSectionName = function(){
    var SectionName = "section-" + this.theID;
    return SectionName;
};
var person2 = new JavaScriptObj(2, "texteditor");
alert(person2.getSectionName);
```

this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxrfT/)

thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: You need to **call** the function: `alert(person2.getSectionName());` Also, `console.log()` is generally better for debugging than `alert()`.

Comment: I do not think that initialize is called explicitly as well. You could defined theID on the object as this.theID = id on line 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `initialize` nested function:

```
function JavaScriptObj(id, datatype) {
    if (typeof id === 'number' && id > 1) {
        this.theID = id;
    } else {
        console.error("ERROR: JavaScriptObj: " + id + "is NOT a valid argument");
    }

    if (typeof datatype === 'string') {
        this.data_type = datatype;
    } else {
        console.error("ERROR: JavaScriptObj: " + datatype + "is NOT a valid argument");
    }
}

JavaScriptObj.prototype.getSectionName = function(){
    var SectionName = "section-" + this.theID;
    return SectionName;
};

var person2 = new JavaScriptObj(2, "texteditor");
alert(person2.getSectionName()); // need to call it too
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not actually executing/calling your method.  In order to call your method, you need to append parenthesis to the call:

```
alert(person2.getSectionName());
```

Small aside -- using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` tends to save you a few keystrokes and makes development a bit faster.  Also, `alert()` is a blocking call that stops all other code execution on the page.  While that won't make a difference when you're first starting out, it could potentially be a pain point down the road as your javascript ninja skills increase.  :)